# How to access JWT in registration handler using Auth provider (open id)

Tags: jwt, open-id-connect, user-registration, registration-handler

In our org we have an open Id auth provider setup that works fine along with the registration handler. The only issue is we are receiving only the email currently from the provider in the auth.UserData.

The provider is storing their UID as a custom attribute and they cannot pass it in the standard Auth.UserData. They are passing the JWT claim from the JWT received as part of the login.

The provider allows users to change emails, therefore a new user would be created in salesforce with the current setup if they change their emails with the provider.

Is it possible to access a claim in the JWT received as part of login within the registration class?

Comment: The stuff coming back in `Auth.UserData` is based on OIDC `UserInfo` endpoint ([docs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo)). If you need additional claims, ask your OIDC provider to expose them via `UserInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it appears with how they are set up that they cannot pass it via UserInfo. Was wondering if the claim could be parsed from the JWT.

Comment: With OpenID Connect auth provider - no. You'd have to roll your own provider.

Comment: Thanks for the response @identigral